# Error 400 when commenting on ruby on rails ecommerce web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm actually making an ecommerce web app which has a `User`, `Category`, `Book` and `Comment` models. Everything is working nice, but when I try to comment in one of the book, it gives a 400 error. I really need you to help me out. https://github.com/felixpro/Book-app this is my repository.

This is my **CommentsController**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    book = Book.find(params[:comment][:book_id])
    comment = book.comments.build(comment_params)
    comment.user = current_user
  ​
    if comment.save
      redirect_to book_path(@book)
    end
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

end
```

This is the comment view partial,

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="card bg-light new-comment">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="font-weight-bold">Deja tu comentario:</p>
      <%= form_for @book.comments.build do |f| %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :book_id, value: @book.id %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 4, class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
​
        <div class="text-right">
          <%= f.submit "Comentar", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="card bg-light mt-5">
    <div class="card-body">
      <p class="card-text text-center lead"><%= link_to "Regístrate", new_user_registration_path %> o <%= link_to "Ingresa", new_user_session_path %> para comentar</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Here are the routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'books#index'
   resources :books

   resources :comments, only: [:create]

 end
```

**The error say**

[This is a pictures showing the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa1s0.png)

Comment: did you have a route for book show page ?

Comment: Please, add routes.rb and server logs for create action with full error backtrace

Comment: HI! Thanks for the fast answer, I edit my question and I added the routes.

Comment: can you share the input and some more error details

Comment: please commit your changes and push them on github i will have a look and let you know the issue

Comment: it seems like you have a ` charachter in your comment controller near private

Comment: HI Wasipeer, in the top I added a a pictures showing the error description. My problem is that, when I make a comment and I press submit to the comment form, it gives me the error 400.

Comment: please push your latest code on Github so that I can locate the issue

Comment: Hi Wasipper, I pushed my change to github.

Comment: I think the issue is that you have book variable and in redirect_to book_path(@book) you have @book. So try to change '@book' with book and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you mentioned is linked to the fact that you have a special invisible character (non-breaking space) at line 9 and 14 in your CommentsController. This is why you get the

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `​' for ...)
```

This often happens when you hit an additional key at the same time you hit the space bar (cmd + space bar on MacOS). Delete those empty lines and type the enter key again to clear the character.

Then the other answer is right, you'll have have to update your book variable name.

Comment: Nice catch. Couldn't possibly see that at a glance!

Comment: Thanks! it takes some practice and some hours debugging to track those ones!

Answer (score 0):

You have referred to `@book` when the variable is a local `book`. Use `@` at the beginning of the line 6:

> `@book = Book.find(params[:comment][:book_id])`